# Is the arithmetic - geometric mean of 1 and 2 rational?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, real-numbers

It is easy to show that, fixed two real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$ $>0$, the sequences given by $a_1 = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}$, $g_1 = \sqrt{\alpha \beta}$, and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n+g_n}{2}$, $g_{n+1} = \sqrt{a_n g_n}$ are both convergent and that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n$ = $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} g_n$. Let's call this limit $agm(\alpha, \beta)$. I am convinced that the number $agm(1,2)$ is irrational, but i don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Well, when rewritten as $$ \operatorname{agm}(1,2)=\frac{\pi}{2\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{1+3\sin^2\theta}}}$$ it at least doesn't directly suggest being rational :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen [I think](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean) your $3$ should be $-1/9$, while your $2$ should be $4/3$.

Comment: @J.G. I think you are referring to $$\operatorname{agm}(1,2)=\frac{3\pi}{4\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\sqrt{1-\frac19\sin^2\theta}}} $$ :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen If you change the $1/0$ to $1/9$, yes.

Comment: @J.G.With that typo correction, both expresion should be the same (both appear on WP at least, in the first I only simplified $1^2\cos^2 + 2^2\sin^2$ to $1+3\sin^2$). This is beginnig to be too convoluted for a remark meant more as a joke :)  -- On a more serious note, could it be possible to show specifically that agm(1,2) is transcendental because can be approximated by rationals too well?

Comment: We know that $\mathrm{agm}(1,1)=1$ is rational and that $\mathrm{agm}(1, \sqrt{2})$ is transcendental, but i think that for no other value of $x$ the character of $\mathrm{agm}(1,x)$ is known. Since this is probably an open question, i believe you should try the more advanced forum [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)